# Save video in document directory continuously after downloading video using URLSession

Tags: ios, video

I want to download and play video from remote url. For that first i am downloading video using url session and after downloading, saving video to document directory and then playing video from document directory. But using this approach i have to wait until my whole video gets downloaded and only then i can save it to document directory and play. But what i want to achieve is that i want to save downloaded part of video continuously to document directory so that i can play it continuously from document directory and i don't have to wait until whole video completes downloading. So is there any way i can get downloaded part of video continuously so that i can save it to document directory. Is there any delegate of url session that can give me already downloaded part or something.

I have used url session for downloading and it's didFinishDownloadingTo only called once download completes.Below is my code that i tried till now.

```
     public func downloadVideo(url: URL) {
         let session = URLSession(configuration: .default, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
         let downloadTask = session.downloadTask(with: url)
         downloadTask.resume()
   }
  
    extension MediaCacheManager: URLSessionDownloadDelegate {
    
      public func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {
        guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: location) else {
            return
        }

        guard let applicationSupportDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else {
            print("Application Support directory not found")
            return
        }
        
        // Create a subdirectory within Application Support, if needed
        let subdirectoryURL = applicationSupportDirectory.appendingPathComponent("telehealthVideo")
        do {
            try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: subdirectoryURL, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
        } catch {
            print("Error creating subdirectory: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }
        
        let destinationURL = subdirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent("myVideo.mp4")
        do {
            print("destinationURL \(destinationURL)")
            try data.write(to: destinationURL)
            //saveVideoToAlbum(videoURL: destinationURL, albumName: "MyAlbum")
        } catch {
            print("Error saving file:", error)
        }}
    
    public func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64) {
        
        print(Float(totalBytesWritten) / Float(totalBytesExpectedToWrite))
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
           
            self.progress = (Float(totalBytesWritten) / Float(totalBytesExpectedToWrite))
            debugPrint("progress \(self.progress)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out [these search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bios%5D+play+video+while+downloading).

Comment: Okay @HangarRash i will check. Thanks for suggestions